# Stop jQuery from executing/evaluating .html() command and running scripts

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to traverse a DOM tree from a resultText string of document.documentElement.innerHTML using jQuery.

**Code**

```
console.log(request.data);
sourceDOM = $('<html>').html(request.data);
```

When line 1 runs, I can see the full source code including all scripts.

When line 2 runs, I get a few lines of Refused to load the script because it violates the following *Content Security Policy directive errors:

> script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'

When I examine the `sourceDOM` through the console, I only see the `html` and all the script tags have been removed.

How can I assign HTML to a JQuery variable that doesn't then execute it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking how to set the _text_?

Comment: I'm asking how to take a string representation of a page's source code and turn it into a DOM tree so I can traverse it using jQuery to find elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(request.data);
sourceDOM = $(request.data);
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems to give me what I want. 

Is there a reason I see #text values every other index in the array? ex -
[#text, <meta http-equiv=​"Content-Type" content=​"text/​html;​charset=iso-8859-1">​, #text...

Comment: The code is the same. I'm just opening the console window and entering sourceDOM. I think it's ok thought since I'll be using sourceDOM.filter to get what I'm looking for and ignore the #text values.

Comment: You should be able to use the "sourceDOM" in the same way as any other jquery object.